# Converting CURSOR that does UPDATE to CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am familiar with CURSORS, but have no experience of CTE's and have never really used them but have been advised that they are a better option than CURSOR's

To try and understand the logic of CTE's, I have written the following CURSOR which I hope to convert to a CTE. Can somebody help me?

```
DECLARE @CustomerID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

DECLARE SalesOrderCursor CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT CustomerID FROM OrdersProcessed

OPEN SalesOrderCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM SalesOrderCursor INTO @CustomerID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE CustomerOrderStatus SET Shipped = 1 WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID

    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM SalesOrderCursor INTO @CustomerID 
END
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just use the following command

```
UPDATE CustomerOrderStatus 
SET Shipped = 1 
WHERE CustomerID IN
(
    SELECT CustomerID FROM OrdersProcessed
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use neither CURSOR nor CTE for this case.

```
UPDATE s
  SET Shipped = 1 
FROM CustomerOrderStatus s
  JOIN OrdersProcessed o ON s.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, there is definitely no need for a cursor in your example, so if you thought there was, what has been suggested needs to become your default thinking ASAP as cursors are pretty grim things, and their performance is usually horrible, therefore should only be used when necessary.

If you were just using it as an example, and how CTE would be used to do the equivalent, then:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  OP.CustomerID 
    FROM    OrdersProcessed     AS OP
)
UPDATE      CO
SET         CO.Shipped          =   1
FROM        CustomerOrderStatus AS CO  
INNER JOIN  CTE                 AS  CT  ON  CT.CustomerID   =   CO.CustomerID;
```

There is no need for recursion in the example you have there, and for the example, the other answers are much better than using CTE. You would normally replace a cursor with recursive CTE: Read about that, here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

That resource gives some examples and a walk through, so hopefully should help.