# SQL Server - Avoid cursor while serial update

Tags: sql-server, serialization, sql-update, cursor, common-table-expression

How can I avoid use cursor to implement the following? I read that it can be done with CTE but I didn't get it working with the same result.

In the example I am using two tables, the first one is the holders table containing a list of people, and the transfers table where each transfer indicates a change at a specific record of the first table.

Below you can see the code, which brings the right results:

```
create table #holders(Person VARCHAR(50), Kind VARCHAR(50), Pctg FLOAT)
create table #transfers(Person_FROM VARCHAR(50), Person_To VARCHAR(50), Kind VARCHAR(50), Pctg_New FLOAT, Eff_Date DATE)

insert into #holders
select 'Person One', 'Kind 1', 50 union all
select 'Person Two', 'Kind 1', 50 union all
select 'Person Three', 'Kind 1', NULL union all
select 'Person Four', 'Kind 1', NULL union all
select 'Person One', 'Kind 2', 100

insert into #transfers
select 'Person One', 'Person A', 'Kind 1', 70, '2019-12-31' union all
select 'Person Two', 'Person B', 'Kind 1', 30, '2020-01-01' union all
select 'Person A', 'Person A1', 'Kind 1', 70, '2020-01-02' union all
select 'Person A', 'Person A2', 'Kind 1', 70, '2020-01-03' union all --Should Avoided
select 'Person A2', 'Person A3', 'Kind 1', 70, '2020-01-04' union all --Should Avoided
select 'Person A1', 'Person A4', 'Kind 1', 70, '2020-01-05' 

declare
    @Person_FROM        varchar(50),
    @Person_To          varchar(50),
    @Kind               varchar(50),
    @Pctg_New           float

declare cur cursor for select Person_FROM, Person_To, Kind, Pctg_New from #transfers order by Eff_Date
open cur
fetch next from cur into @Person_FROM, @Person_To, @Kind, @Pctg_New
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
    update #holders set Person = @Person_To, Pctg = @Pctg_New where Person = @Person_FROM AND Kind = @Kind
    fetch next from cur into @Person_FROM, @Person_To, @Kind, @Pctg_New
end
close cur
deallocate cur

SELECT * FROM #holders

drop table #holders
drop table #transfers
```

The (correct) results are the following:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XhCZ.png)

Comment: Is this just for learning? I only ask as a very similar question has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153033/converting-cursor-that-does-update-to-cte/46155332#46155332

Comment: Hi Leonida, thanks for your comment. I  think actually this is not the case, since here the update is required to be serialized (Example: "Person One" --> "Person A" --> "Person A1" --> "Person A1" --> "Person A4")

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `update`/`join`:

```
update h
     set Person = t.Person_To,
         Pctg = t/Pctg_New 
from #holders h join
     #transfers t
     on h.person = t.person_from and h.kind = t.kind;
```

No explicit looping is needed.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, 

Thanks for your answer. 

Using cursor the (correct) results line-by-line was: 
"Person A4", "Person B", "Person Three", "Person Four" and "Person One". 

Using this update query the results are similar for all persons except the first one: Specifically: "Person A", "Person B", "Person Three", "Person Four" & "Person One". 

I think the problem is that it is needed serialized update (order by Eff_Date) and some kind of recursive (The first line should updated 4 times using this flow: 
"Person One" --> "Person A" --> "Person A1" --> "Person A1" --> "Person A4").

Comment: @SteliosBobolakis . . . You don't need a cursor for this and it is better not to use one.

Comment: I aggree but the results are not the same!